# HASP key does not work over ssh

Tags: linux, security, udev

I am using a software product that uses a HASP USB dongle. The software runs on a Linux box and I would like to run it remotely via ssh (it is a command line software tool). When I am physically on the workstation I can run the tool. When I login via ssh, it says it cannot find the License key.

My other team members use the software tool (separate installation) and are able to use it remotely. I just installed this thing and I can't seem to use it remotely. There isn't much documentation on this HASP dongle and I am not sure if there some super-tight restriction - I think some debug feedback would be great.

Note I am not trying to do anything outside the ordinary. I rebooted the machine and the behavior was still the same. I am thinking that maybe the HASP (UDEV rules) do not permit network users?

Any thoughts guidance would be informative.

Comment: If one colleague is able to run it remotely and you not, could be different access methods or license limitations, or even number of seats. We cannot guess, you would better ask the vendor/supplier.

Comment: or the people resonsible of those dongle at your company

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will look into it ... The dongle and tool documentation does not list limitations related to remote users so it is a bit of a head scratcher. I will send an email to the tool vendor and also ask them to update their documentation accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This restriction is intentional. The design is supposed to prevent misuse by only allowing "local" access to the license, which includes viewing it. "local" means console (text-based or graphical).

You can get around this restriction when connected via ssh by running "sudo tmux". This puts you in a tmux session as root. You must use sudo even if you are already logged in as root.